# Confirming validity of schematic for dual stepper motor PCB

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, pcb-design, motor, circuit-design

I'm trying to make my first schematic for a PCB that would sit atop an RPI and allow for control of two stepper motors. I have an LM2576 to take 12v from the motor supply and step it down to 5v for the RPI, and I took the schematic from Pololu's [DRV8225](https://www.pololu.com/product/2133) as the driver for the motors.

I did however modify a couple of things, such as add a single capacitor to act as voltage spike protection for both the LM2576 and the two DRV8225 ics. I also tethered reset and sleep to 5v on the board, and enable as I would want to keep the driver running so long as the board is on.

I am just very worried that if I order the PCB there's no turning back, so I want to make sure I have everything right before I start. My biggest ask is that on Pololu's schematic for the DRV8225, they have this circuit separate from the ic off to the side, I assumed that if it changed the power supply, I would only need one per board despite having two of the driver ics.

Here is my schematic so far, which I have designed in easy eda
[image: my current schematic]
[And here is a link to a pdf if this is too blurry](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NSZCnOC-xA4a88oSNM4Nz-5gzA5n9yAz/view?usp=sharing)

I just really want to know if this would work with the way I have it set up, I'm sorry if some of my design (or all of it) is unorthodox in methods, this is my first time so go easy on me aha.

Comment: I went to Pololu to find 8255 details, and found it good.
DRV8825 Stepper Motor Driver Carrier, High Current - Pololu
https://www.pololu.com/product/2133. Question - have you consider more updated driver modules?

Comment: 2576 seems not so popular as 2596, which seems to be a little bit more powerful. Have you also consider yet even more powerful, say 5A, 10A switching PSU modules?

Comment: Are you not driving the Step/Dir pins from the Rpi GPIO? BTW, you may need a more complex power supply or filtering to avoid resetting your Pi during spikes.

Comment: First up, understand that this is a tricky pcb to design and get it to work properly. Your lm2576 circuit needs an input capacitor (not for voltage spike protection) and along with the output capacitor needs to be carefully chosen. Any 1000uF capacitor is not acceptable. Read the datasheet carefully. Due to high frequencies and high currents, the pcb layout is critical. You can design it willy-nilly but you’ll be back here asking why it doesn’t work. Same with the motor chip. Track size and placement make a big difference.